# warning: control reaches end of non-void function (gtk)

Tags: c

I keep getting 'warning: control reaches end of non-void function' with this code:

```
static show_message(GtkMessageType type, const char* text, const char* details)
{
    GtkWidget *dialog;

    g_assert(text);

    dialog = gtk_message_dialog_new(NULL, DIALOG_FLAGS, type, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE,
        "%s", text);
    if (details) {
        gtk_message_dialog_format_secondary_text(GTK_MESSAGE_DIALOG(dialog), "%s", details);
    }
    gtk_dialog_run(GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy(dialog);
}
```

When I compile the above code I get Warning (ie control reaches end of non-void function):

```
gui.c: warning: return type defaults to 'int'
gui.c: In function 'show_message':
gui.c: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

How can I get rid of this warning?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the return value of the `show_message()` function as `void`, otherwise it is assumed `int`.  Like this:

```
static void show_message(GtkMessageType type, const char* text, const char* details)
{
    /* ... */
}
```